# cropping an array list in java [rectangle]

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, arraylist

`crop()` has parameters that are two `Points` in the `Cloud`. One of these two `Points` is a bottom corner, and the other the top corner of a rectangle, located diagonally across from the first `Point`. `crop()` will remove all points outside this rectangle from the `Cloud`, much like you would crop an image. The `crop()` method must deal with two input points on a horizontal or vertical line segment, in which case all points not on the line segment are removed, and it must deal with two equal `Points` `p1` and `p2`, in which case all `Points` but `p1` are removed from the Cloud.

For example, if the two input `Points` are `(0.0,0,0)` and `(1.0,1.0)`, all Points outside the square delimited by `(0.0,0.0)`, `(0.0,1.0)`, `(1.0,1.0)`, and `(0.0,1.0)` are removed, but if the two input `Points` are `(0.0,0,0)` and `(0.0,1.0)`, all Points outside the line segment delimited by `(0.0,0.0)`, and `(0.0,1.0)` are removed.

So if you have final cloud: `[(3.0,1.0), (2.0,2.0), (1.5,1.5), (3.0,0.0)]` you should get cropped cloud: `[(3.0,1.0), (3.0,0.0)]`

At this point I really want to know a solution cause I'm so frustrated that I can't figure it out... So any help or suggestions about how you guys would solve it would be nice. I came pretty close, but I was just missing one main thing.

I had this:

```
public void crop(Point p1, Point p2) {
    double highX = 0;
    double lowX = 0;
    double highY = 0;
    double lowY = 0;
    double x1 = p1.getX();
    if (p1.getX() > p2.getX()) {
        highX = p1.getX();
        lowX = p2.getX();
    } else {
        highX = p2.getX();
        lowX = p1.getX();
    }
    if (p1.getY() > p2.getY()) {
        highY = p1.getY();
        lowY = p2.getY();
    } else {
        highY = p2.getY();
        lowY = p1.getY();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        Point P = points.get(i);
        if (P.getX() < lowX || P.getX() > highX || P.getY() < lowY
                || P.getY() > highY) {
            points.remove(i);
        }

        if (P.getX() == lowX && P.getX() == highX && P.getY() == lowY
                && P.getY() == highY) {
            points.remove(i);
        }

    }

    // vertical
    if (p1.getX() == p2.getX()) {
        double x = p1.getX();
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            if (points.get(i).getX() == x
                    && p1.getY() <= points.get(i).getY()
                    && points.get(i).getY() >= p2.getY()) {
                continue;
            } else {
                points.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
    // Horizontal
    if (p1.getY() == p2.getY()) {
        double y = p2.getY();
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            if (points.get(i).getY() == y) {
                if (p1.getX() <= points.get(i).getX()
                        && points.get(i).getX() >= p2.getX()) {
                    continue;
                }
            } else {
                points.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
    // square
    if (p1.getX() == p2.getX()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            if (points.get(i).getY() <= p1.getY()
                    && points.get(i).getY() >= p2.getY()) {
                if (points.get(i).getX() >= p1.getX()
                        && points.get(i).getX() <= p2.getX()) {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            points.remove(i);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it not possible to get help from your prof and/or a TA? Also, this: "at this point i really want to know a solution... So any help or how you guys would solve it would be nice" --> Stack Overflow is **not** about answering broad "I'm stuck, can you please help" questions. "This question does not show any research effort" is a downvote reason, and people taking lack of debugging effort as a downvote reason is not uncommon. You haven't described the problem you are facing beyond "it doesn't work", and haven't described any debugging efforts either.

Comment: From the close menu: "Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it* **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)." Just pasting your homework and attempted solution here makes it difficult to help you. Please add more details.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you only need this condition :

```
    if (P.getX() < lowX || P.getX() > highX || P.getY() < lowY
            || P.getY() > highY) {
        points.remove(i);
    }
```

The second condition (below) is wrong. It would remove the point in the case that P=P1=P2, which is exactly the opposite of what you want to do.

```
    if (P.getX() == lowX && P.getX() == highX && P.getY() == lowY
            && P.getY() == highY) {
        points.remove(i);
    }
```

Even if you got this condition right, it would still be redundant, since if P1=P2, the first condition (above) would remove any point that is not equal to P1. Furthermore, your first condition also takes care of the case where P1 and P2 form a horizontal or vertical line segment, so all the rest of your code is either wrong or redundant too.

All you need is this :

```
public void crop(Point p1, Point p2) {
    double highX = 0;
    double lowX = 0;
    double highY = 0;
    double lowY = 0;
    double x1 = p1.getX();
    if (p1.getX() > p2.getX()) {
        highX = p1.getX();
        lowX = p2.getX();
    } else {
        highX = p2.getX();
        lowX = p1.getX();
    }
    if (p1.getY() > p2.getY()) {
        highY = p1.getY();
        lowY = p2.getY();
    } else {
        highY = p2.getY();
        lowY = p1.getY();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        Point P = points.get(i);
        if (P.getX() < lowX || P.getX() > highX || P.getY() < lowY
                || P.getY() > highY) {
            points.remove(i);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: even with such code which i tired you still get the wrong answer you get something like this

Comment: inPoints before crop:[(0.0,1.0), (1.0,0.0), ( inPoints before crop:[(0.0,1.0), (1.0,0.0), (
Extremes before crop: [(0.0,1.0), (2.0,2.0),  Extremes before crop: [(0.0,1.0), (2.0,2.0), 

inPoints after crop:[(2.0,2.0)]        | inPoints after crop:[(2.0,2.0), (2.0,0.0)]
Extremes after crop: [(2.0,2.0), (2.0,2.0), ( | Extremes after crop: [(2.0,2.0), (2.0,2.0), (

test1 Score: 0 / 1
--------------------

Comment: @user3785202 I'm sorry, but your example is not clear. What do you mean by `inPoints` and `Extremes`? Are `inPoints` the input ArrayList and `Extremes` the two points that form the cropping rectangle? If that's the case, how can `Extremes` change after the crop? And how can `inPoints` contain completely different points after the crop? The crop only removes some points, it doesn't add new points or change existing points.

Comment: I have other test as such Your Output/Master Output:

grid:      grid:
[(0.0,0.0), (0.0,1.0), (0.0,2.0), (1.0,0.0),  [(0.0,0.0), (0.0,1.0), (0.0,2.0), (1.0,0.0), 
grid cropped at (1,1):    grid cropped at (1,1):
[(0.0,0.0), (0.0,1.0), (1.0,0.0), (1.0,1.0),  | [(0.0,0.0), (0.0,1.0), (1.0,0.0), (1.0,1.0)]
grid cropped at (0,1):    grid cropped at (0,1):
[(2.0,2.0)]          | [(0.0,0.0), (0.0,1.0)]
grid cropped at (0,0):    grid cropped at (0,0):
[]

Comment: @user3785202 It's hard to understand what the numbers in your comments mean. Please edit your question, and write there clearly the input (the ArrayList, P1 and P2), the expected output and the output that you actually got.